# open recordset without cursors

Tags: database, asp-classic, recordset

generally, i connect to db with the following statement;

> rs.open "query",db,1,3

now i tried (without cursors)

> rs.open "query",db

the new one bring a big performance increase.

so i like to ask you if i don't set cursors in connection, what cursors are default?

Comment: look here for cursor usage http://www.w3schools.com/ADO/met_rs_open.asp

Comment: You can also have `Set rs = db.Execute("query")` which will use the default cursors and save you one line of code.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
LockType = adLockReadOnly
```

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

What you had were adOpenKeyset and adLockOptimistic.